# replace null values in subsequent rows from previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table about foods and rating and facing this scenario.

```
select * from foods
```

| food_type | country | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pizza | Italy | 8 |
| Pizza | Italy | null |
| Pizza | Italy | null |
| Pizza | Sweden | 6 |
| Pizza | Sweden | null |
| Pizza | Sweden | null |
| Calzone | France | 7 |
| Calzone | France | null |
| Calzone | France | null |
| Hero Sub | USA | 10 |
| Hero Sub | USA | null |
| Hero Sub | USA | null |
| Hero Sub | USA | null |

How can I replace the **nulls** with the rating value of the same food_type and same country from the previous not null rating value? e.g. **new_rating column**

| food_type | country | rating | new_rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pizza | Italy | 8 | 8 |
| Pizza | Italy | null | 8 |
| Pizza | Italy | null | 8 |
| Pizza | Sweden | 6 | 6 |
| Pizza | Sweden | null | 6 |
| Pizza | Sweden | null | 6 |
| Calzone | France | 7 | 7 |
| Calzone | France | null | 7 |
| Calzone | France | null | 7 |
| Hero Sub | USA | 10 | 10 |
| Hero Sub | USA | null | 10 |
| Hero Sub | USA | null | 10 |
| Hero Sub | USA | null | 10 |

I am using postgreSQL 11.4!

Answer (score 1):

Try a coalesce'd `MAX OVER`

```
SELECT food_type, country, rating
, COALESCE(rating, MAX(rating) OVER (PARTITION BY food_type, country)) AS new_rating
FROM foods
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Subquery in the SELECT-Part - like this:

https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

```
select 
  master.*,
  (select 
    newfood.rating 
   from 
    foods newfood 
   where 
    newfood.food_type = master.food_type AND newfood.country = master.country
    AND newfood.rating is not NULL
   group by newfood.rating
  ) as new_rating
from 
  foods master
;
```